# Server.MapPath not accepting UNC URL

Tags: asp.net, url, unc, mappath

I'm having a bit of trouble loading an XML file with ASP. 
This is the location of the XML file (it's a UNC url):

```
\\ilife104\teamdisk\Shared\Integration\System\dev\Data\prcImportFactSetFeeds\fileList.xml
```

And this is my code:

```
<% 
'load the XML file.. 
Option Explicit
Response.Buffer = True

Dim xml
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.async = False
xml.load (Server.MapPath("\\ilife104\teamdisk\Shared\Integration\System\dev\Data\prcImportFactSetFeeds\fileList.xml"))

Dim name, retrieved 
name = xml.documentElement.childNodes(0).text
retrieved = xml.documentElement.childNodes(2).text

Set xml = Nothing
%>
```

It gives the error:

```
Server.MapPath() error 'ASP 0174 : 80004005'

Invalid Path Character(s)

/ITWeb/Interfaces/je/index.asp, line 9

An invalid '/' or '\' was found in the Path parameter for the MapPath method.
```

Does anybody know a solution?? 
Thanks in advance, James.

Comment: Why are you calling `MapPath`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` takes a page-relative path (eg, `../Images/Something.png`) and returns a full path on disk.

Since you already have a file path, you should not call `Server.MapPath` at all.

Answer (score 0):

needs to be

```
\\\\servername\\folder\\folder\\whateverfileyouwant.ext
```

you have to escape the characters